# How to set up remote development in Eclipse for Python? (the "remote" part)

Tags: python, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am new to Eclipse and I would like to set it up for remote development in Python. I use Eclipse on Win7, the sources being on a Linux machine (and expected to run from there).

I have used excellent guides to set up [Eclipse for remote dev](http://www.patrickjwaters.com/blog/2011-07-24/how-setup-eclipse-php-pdt-remote-system-explorer-theme-manager-and-drupal-plugins/35) and [PyDEV](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm) and I now have:

- a working copy of Eclipse with PyDEV
- access to my remote files via sftp from within Eclipse

What I am missing now is the ability to actually run the files remotely, ie. I do not know the magic to make it so that when I execute the files from Eclipse they are run through /usr/bin/python on the Linux box with the output nicely managed by Eclipse (at least this is the dream part :)).

Thanks!

Comment: @Péter Varga, Where did the OP stated that the remote box is production server?

Comment: @Péter Varga -- I do not get your comment. My question was not about software development methodology and associated risks but about how to use Eclipse in remote mode.

Comment: I am looking for the same. Please let me know if you found any way to do it. I heard something about "Remote Workspace Preferences Plug-in" but not getting what exactly required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say I haven't tested this, but from what I know, you should be able to launch the file remotely as explained in: https://serverfault.com/questions/36419/using-ssh-to-remotely-start-a-process right?

Now, provided you have that step working, you could either create a python script (i.e.: launch_my_project_remotely.py) and make it call that command line **or** create an external launcher (run > external tools).

Note that you can associate a keybinding to 'run last launched external tool' in window > preferences > general > keys.

p.s.: note that you may also be interested in remote debugging in this case. For that see: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

p.s.2.: personally, I don't really like a setup like this and prefer being totally remote (i.e.: http://nomachine.com/) or just doing all locally and having a http://jenkins-ci.org/ server to make continuous integration of things I commit in different environments.

Comment: @WoJ: Do you have detailed instructions on setting up the remote running and debugging of python projects on remote hosts. If so can you pls share

Comment: I don't, but from a deleted answer from @Martin Koubek, https://sites.google.com/site/programmersnotebook/remote-development-of-python-scripts-on-raspberry-pi-with-eclipse has instructions...